# Odd Memcached server behavior when reading data with a certain length

Tags: c#, memcached, couchbase

I wrote a simple couchbase/memcached client in C# and recently ran into some odd behavior with the couchbase server.  If the length of the data plus key are between 1004-1008 characters the server adds an extra blank line to the end of the data.  I was wondering if this was intended behavior or a bug?  I have also tested this on a freshly installed memcached server on OSX and got the same result.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        char[] charArray = new char[959];
        for (int x = 0; x < 959; x++)
        {
            charArray[x] = ' ';
        }
        string data = new string(charArray);

        string key = Couchbase.kurogoKeyCode + "2090Event";
        string json = String.Empty;
        using (Couchbase.Client client = new Couchbase.Client())
        {
            client.Set(key, data, 0);
            json = client.Read(key);
            Console.WriteLine(json);
            client.Read(key);
            Console.WriteLine(json);  // <-- This line outputs the header instead of the data b/c the streamreader is off a line
                                      //     I added and commented out a fix in the read method
        }
    }
}

public class Couchbase
{
    public const string kurogoKeyCode = "51e2b57ace3c5364dd10a33e1f34a44c-XX-";

    public class Client : IDisposable
    {
        private TcpClient tcpClient;
        private NetworkStream networkStream;
        private StreamReader streamReader;
        private StreamWriter streamWriter;

        public Client()
        {
            tcpClient = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 11211);
            networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            streamReader = new StreamReader(networkStream);
            streamWriter = new StreamWriter(networkStream);
            networkStream.ReadTimeout = 200;
        }

        public bool Disconnect()
        {
            streamWriter.Write("quit\r\n");
            streamWriter.Flush();
            tcpClient.Close();
            return true;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            this.Disconnect();
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }

        public string Read(string key)
        {
            try
            {
                streamWriter.WriteLine("get " + key);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                string header = streamReader.ReadLine();
                if (header == null)
                    return String.Empty;
                string json = streamReader.ReadLine();
                streamReader.DiscardBufferedData();
                //while (networkStream.DataAvailable)
                //    streamReader.ReadLine();
                return json;
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }

        public bool Set(string key, string value, int secondsToLive = 0)
        {
            string returnValue = String.Empty;
            streamWriter.WriteLine("set " + key + " 0 " + secondsToLive + " " + value.Length);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.WriteLine(value);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            while (!networkStream.DataAvailable)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(25);
            }
            returnValue = streamReader.ReadLine();
            if (returnValue == "STORED")
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        public bool Delete(string key)
        {
            string returnValue = String.Empty;
            try
            {
                streamWriter.WriteLine("delete " + key);
                streamWriter.Flush();
                while (!networkStream.DataAvailable)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(25);
                }
                returnValue = streamReader.ReadLine();
                if (returnValue == "DELETED")
                    return true;
                return false;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: - what version of couchbase server/client are you using? Also have you tried doing a manual add from couchbase admin console for same input and observed the same behavior?

Comment: Version: 2.2.0 enterprise edition (build-821)